# Where is the Render on Save checkbox in Rstudio for Quarto documents?

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

For some reason, even though I have the most recent versions of Rstudio Desktop and Quarto, my toolbar does not show the **Render on Save** checkbox. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12998) in the Rstudio Github repository, but I thought that maybe someone here has faced the same problem.

I know that my question is not directly related with code, but please, do not close it!, the answer to my question will help me and many others in their coding using Rstudio and Quarto.

Thank you so much in advanced. Please find below the problem in detail.

Best,

#### System details

```
RStudio Edition : Desktop
RStudio Version : 2023.03.0+386 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
OS Version      : Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
R Version       : R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
```

#### Steps to reproduce the problem

My toolbar does not show the **Save on render** checkbox when working on Quarto documents:

[image]

#### Describe the problem in detail

I have tried to find the solution on the web without success:

I saw [this question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/render-on-save-not-on-toolbar/149384) in the Posit community but it does not have an answer (at least not visible to me).

I also noticed that other people have [the same problem](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12838#issue-1623476584) even though they have not properly reported it.

#### Describe the behavior you expected

I expect to have a functional Save on Render checkbox as explained in the [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#render-and-preview):
[image]

Comment: In my Rstudio version `"2022.07.2+576"`, release name `"Spotted Wakerobin"` (Desktop)  has this **Render on Save** checkbox. And if I check the Rstudio from my posit cloud account, which is `"2023.03.0+386.pro1" "Cherry Blossom"`, does not have this checkbox.